# UIGestureRecognizer - reset is never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating custom gesture recognizer. The problem is that reset method is never called so I can't reset the state of recognizer. As result it works only for the first time

```
@implementation TouchGestureRecognizer {

    UIGestureRecognizerState mState;
}

-(UIGestureRecognizerState) state {
    return mState;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if( [touches count] == 1 ) {
        mState = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if( [touches count] == 1 ) {
        mState = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
    }
}

- (void)reset {
    mState = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mState = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
}

@end
```

Comment: try this,`- (void)reset:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mState = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> The runtime calls this method after the gesture-recognizer state has been set to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded or UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized.

It seems that is what you are doing in `touchesEnded:`. Put a breakpoint in this method and take it from there.

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event is invoked and state is set to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, however reset is not invoked

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this in your .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```